# Making URL, that keeps updating which is generated by span and id, clickable and opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, href, window.open

I am trying to make a URL clickable and open in new window. This is how the URL being displayed and updated on my html page:

Python Code:

```
def data_cb():

   return jsonify(waiting=await_take_pic())
```

Javascript Code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var tab = 1;

        function update_values() {
            $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT+"/_data",
                function(data) {
                    $("#waiting").text(data.waiting)
                });
            if(tab == 1){
                setTimeout(update_values, 3000);
            }
        }
```

HTML Code:

```
<p>Picture URL Update: <span id="waiting"></span></p>
```

This html line displays URL that keeps updating as pictures are being taken. If we copy and paste the URL on a new window then we can display the picture.

I have tried all sort of combinations and syntax to make href, open.window, or onclick to make the URL clickable and opens the picture in new window but I haven't been successful (it really needs to be taken from http//...to the end of the link and be placed exactly as it appears). I am very new to python, javascript and html. In fact, this is my first project working with them so I need as much info and details as possible when suggesting answers, please.TIA

Comment: The suggested answer below did work "Picture URL Update:" is just a text. The real URL is generated between where it says HERE <span id="waiting"></span>HERE</p> What you suggested in the first line made the generated URL clickable but it still does not open it. It really needs to grap the whole text to open it. As I stated the generated URL is displayed as: http://192.168.122.1:8080/postview/memory/DCIM/101MSDCF/DSC08235.JPG?size=Scn

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to generate the page with the URL pre-set as a link:

```
 <p>Picture <a href="URL" target="_blank">URL</a> Update: <span id="waiting"></span></p>
```

This will make the URL clickable and open in a new window.  Then you can adjust your image rotation code to modify the `href` attribute as needed when the image changes.

To make it easier to access the link, you could add an id attribute (e.g. `<a id="imageLink" ...>`) so that you can set the URL with something like:

```
document.getElementById('imageLink').setAttribute('href', URL);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did work "Picture URL Update:" is just a text. The real URL is generated between where it says HERE <span id="waiting"></span>HERE</p> What you suggested in the first line made the generated URL clickable but it still does not open it. It really needs to grap the whole text to open it. As I stated the generated URL is displayed as: http://192.168.122.1:8080/postview/memory/DCIM/101MSDCF/DSC08235.JPG?size=Scn

Comment: Can you update the question with the actual generated source? and/or what is populating the data? I'm sure we can solve it once we have all the info.